# TF-IDF Simple Use - NLTK/Scikit Learn

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, scikit-learn, tf-idf

Okay so I am a little confused. This should be a simple straightforward question however.

After calculating the TF-IDF Matrix of the Document against the entire corpus, I get a result very similar to this:

```
array([[ 0.85...,  0.  ...,  0.52...],
       [ 1.  ...,  0.  ...,  0.  ...],
       [ 1.  ...,  0.  ...,  0.  ...],
       [ 1.  ...,  0.  ...,  0.  ...],
       [ 0.55...,  0.83...,  0.  ...],
       [ 0.63...,  0.  ...,  0.77...]])
```

How do I use this result to get the most similar document against the search query? Basically I am trying to re-create a search bar for Wikipedia. Based on a search query I want to return the most relevant articles from Wikipedia. In this scenario, there are 6 articles (rows) and the search query contains 3 words (columns).

Do I add up all the results in the columns or add up all the rows? Is the greater value the most relevant or is the lowest value the most relevant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you familiar with [cosine similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity)? For each article (vector A) compute its similarity to the query (vector B). Then rank in descending order and choose the top result. If you're willing to refactor, the [gensim](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/) library is excellent.

Comment: Well I am actually following this tutorial: http://pyevolve.sourceforge.net/wordpress/?p=1589... What doesnt make sense is how to use TF-IDF Vectors between the original articles and the search query.

Comment: If you're using tf-idf as your weighting scheme, you'd still want to just normalize your query. Your matrix contains three terms, all of which are represented in the query; thus the raw frequency vector of the query is (1,1,1). sqrt((1^2)+(1^2)+(1^2)) = 1.73, and 1/1.73 = 0.57. So your query vector is (0.57,0.57,0.57). Now you can treat the query as another document. The cosine similarity of this query vector and some other document vector is its dot product.  For the first article: ((.57*.85)+(.57*0)+(.57*.52)) = 0.2964. Repeat this for all articles and the highest score wins.

Comment: So I do not have to train a classifier of some sort?

Comment: If I understand your tutorial link correctly, not at this point. I recommend reviewing section 6.2 onwards in [link](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/pdf/06vect.pdf) to first understand tf-idf, etc., and then applying it to machine learning topics. I'm not sure if you're learning both information retrieval and machine learning at once.

Comment: Okay I will look at it... do you have some example code for TDIDF in python? It would really help as I am trying to wrap my head around the concepts. I would like to see it being used directly in search tasks. (Search query and a set of documents to search)

Comment: No code of mine off hand. But seriously, check out that gensim library. Look at the tutorials and the source code; you'll probably find what you're looking for.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15092/discussion-between-tabchas-and-verbsintransit)